# Is there a three-body Hamiltonian that has real applications, and if so what is an example?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, spin-models

I wonder if there is an extension of spin interactions into three-body interactions such as $$H\sim  \sum J \sigma_1\otimes \sigma_2 \otimes \sigma_3.$$

If so, what is a real application in which this would occur?

Comment: Yes. However note that even comments don't allow you to write the words "Yes/No" for an answer, which is why Yes/No questions are discouraged.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a yes/no question which boils down to whether or not a tensor product with three elements is a meaningful expression. If there were a question about the physical relevance or existence of three body interactions it would be on topic.

Comment: I have changed it from a yes/no question to a form more appropriate for stack exchange, can you please re-open it @DanielSank?

Comment: @Aaron Stevens, I don't see why you had to change "any" to "a", but anyway, would you mind re-opening this question now that it's a valid question and has a very good answer below?

Comment: @user1271772 1) I edited the title to be grammatically correct. 2) I am not able to reopen question, and I wasn't even one of the users who voted to close it. 3) The question being closed does not invalidate the answer. 4) IMO the answer is not a good one, for if the links stop working in the future then the answer is pretty much useless.

Comment: @AaronStevens: 1) It was already grammatically correct: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/251220/21450. Can you please change it back? 2) You are able to vote to re-open the question. Can you do it please? 4) I agree that the hyperlinks could have been improved, but it was still a good answer in terms of the physics knowledge that he provided to the asker and to the community. The answer is gone now.. were you the one that deleted it?

Comment: @user1271772 I apologise for my lack of grammar knowledge, but I don't it's worth changing it at this point. I did not delete the answer.

Comment: @AaronStevens: I edited it back to saying "a" instead of "any". Have you rejected the edit? Also, rather than apologizing for what you call a "lack of grammar knowledge", why don't you apologize for what you did? Having a "lack of grammar knowledge" is no problem if you area aware of it and don't do anything harmful to anyone.

Comment: @user1271772 I did not reject any edits on this question. I don't think anyone was harmed by my edit, and I don't think it should be causing this much of an issue. If you have any further issues with how this question and it's answers have been handled, then I suggest raising a custom flag for moderators to review.